# Dynamic product image rendering (color variants)

Tags: svg, rendering, product

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, but what technology/service is used to render the images at cushionsource.com ?

I mean what do they use to "dress" the pillow in 3D with those color swatches

I researched and found Amplience does a similar thing, but those Cushion Source look so much better and realistic (I also couldnt find patterned examples from the Amplience demo, only solid color rendering, but not stripes or florals)

Perhaps Cushion Source is using Amplience? and it's only the quality of the SVG file that matters? Or what else are they using?

[base image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQp0W.jpg)

[rendered image (based on selected variant[fabric])](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNO1m.jpg)

Comment: Hmm nobody knows?

Answer (score 0):

This is Adobe Scene 7.

Support for 3d objects is extensive, you can read more about it in their [official documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/assets/using/3d-assets.html).

Scene7 became highly regarded for rich media and has now evolved into [Adobe Dynamic Media](https://www.adobe.com/ie/marketing-cloud/experience-manager/dynamic-media.html) under the Experience Manager suite.

A little late but hope this helps you all the same.